# Override version name on Android Studio 3.1 fail

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.1

I have the following code to update all application variant when its build type is "release"

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    if (variant.buildType.name == "release") {
        variant.outputs.all { output ->
            output.setVersionNameOverride(output.processResources.versionName + "-build" + new Date().format('yyyyMMddHHmmss'))
        }
    }
}
```

however, when I'm update Android Studio to 3.1 the following error appear please help.

> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>
> > Could not get unknown property 'versionName' for task ':app:processProdReleaseResources' of type
> >     com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think, there are some api changes

```
 android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        if (variant.buildType.name == "debug") {
            variant.outputs.all { output ->
                output.setVersionNameOverride(variant.mergedFlavor.versionName + "-build" + new Date().format('yyyyMMddHHmmss'))
            }
        }
    }
```